# Цикл For в JavaScript в Django Template

Tags: javascript, django, for

Подскажите, как я могу использовать переменные Django Template в JS в цикле For?
Допустим, вот у меня есть цикл:

```
             {% for bc in breadcrumbs %}
                <li>
                    {% for ll in bc %}
                        {% if ll.link %}
                            <a href="{{ll.link}}">{{ ll.name }}</a>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ ll.name }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
```

А мне нужно его же пустить в JS чтобы заполнить вот этот массив

```
    [{
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "name": подставить значение сюда,
        "item": и сюда
      }]
    }]
```

Помогите, пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
[{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [
  {% for bc in breadcrumbs %}
    {% for ll in bc %}
      {% if ll.link %}
      {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": {{ forloop.counter }},
        "name": {{ ll.name }},
        "item": {{ll.link}}
      }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но у меня всё в этих {%  %} тегах красное, пишет что  JSON не поддерживает такие токены...

Comment: У меня <script type="application/ld+json">

Comment: @Elizaveta во-первых, этот код должен быть в шаблоне, а не в отдельном файле. Во-вторых, не верьте подсказкам IDE безоговорочно. JSON - это просто текст в определённом формате. Шаблонизатор этим и занимается - просто генерирует текст. Анализировать его будет браузер в тот момент, когда когда шаблонизатора в этом JSON уже не будет.

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогли!